# How soon can you fly without paying extra?

Tags: air-travel

If I want to book an international flight departing today, I understand I will have to pay a substantial surcharge because the airline reasons that if I have to travel urgently, I have no choice but to pay the extra, compared to the more typical scenario of booking a flight to depart in a few weeks.

What is the minimum lead time required to avoid having to pay extra?

Comment: This will vary depending on each airline and each route, I've bought tickets the day before that were cheaper as they wanted to sell the empty seats off, and I've bought tickets a month before during a flash sale. It all varies so I'm voting to close this as too broad.

Comment: Last minute sales are (still) a thing, as far as I know. Better have somebody pay $10 for an empty seat than not have someone pay.

Comment: It is indeed very variable, especially with low cost carriers that only sell directly. More traditional airlines which also sell via GDS and travel agents have a notion of "fares" and "buckets", and the cheaper fares will often have specific rules such as "booking 7 days before departure" or "booking 15 days before departure", though there may be other rules like "book a return with a Saturday night at the destination" or "book a return at least 7 days later". It's not like there's one "cheap" and one "expensive" fare, though, more like dozens...

Comment: Note also that from the airline's perspective, you're not paying extra when you book late, you're getting a discount where you're booking early :-)